# How to solve this equation for $y$? Is it an irrational number or rational?

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

How to solve this equation for $y$? and is it an irrational number or a rational?

$$\frac{2}{7}\pi^2\log2+\frac{16}{7}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\log(\sin x)\,\mathrm{d}x-\sqrt{y}\pi^3=0.$$

Comment: what's the base of the logarithm?

Comment: @Stahl Do you think $\zeta(3)=\sqrt{y}\pi^3,y\in\mathbb{Q}$ is right?

Comment: You can isolate $y$ without too much trouble, but an explicit value for $\zeta(3)$ is not known. In particular, we don't know if $\zeta(3) = q\pi^3$ for some $q\in\Bbb{Q}$, so it's not clear from your equation whether or not $y\in\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: @daoyi If that is your real question, why didn't you ask directly?

Answer (score 3):

Just "isolate" $\,y\,$ :

$$\sqrt y=\frac{1}{\pi^3}\left(\frac{2}{7}\pi^2\log 2+\frac{16}{7}\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}x\log\sin x\,dx\right)\ldots$$

You may want now to square the whole right hand side, or evaluate explicitly the integral, or...

Answer (score 3):

Well, assuming that the logarithm has base $b$, the integral will be equal to:
$$\frac{16}{7}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\log(\sin x)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\pi ^2 \ln(4)-7 \zeta (3)}{7 \ln(b)},$$
where $\zeta (3)$ - is the  Riemann zeta function.
So 
$$\frac{2}{7}\pi^2\log2+\frac{16}{7}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\log(\sin x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\zeta(3)}{\ln(b)}$$
And $$y={\bigg(\!\!\frac{\zeta(3)}{\ln(b)\pi^3}\!\!\bigg)}^{2}$$
Buy the way [$\zeta (3)$ is proved to be irrational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant).

Comment: Thank you a lot! In fact I know that $b=\mathrm{e}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$. I want to know if $y$ is a rational?

Comment: @daoyi I think it's still open whether $\zeta(3)/\pi^3$ is rational.  We know from numerical evidence that if it is rational, it can't be a very nice one (probably millions of digits long at least).  Presumably no one knows whether $(\zeta(3)/\pi^3)^2$ is rational either.

Comment: @daoyi You have an irrational number (see the link in the answer) divided by an irrational number $\pi$. It's an irrational number.

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache $\sqrt{12}/\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: @ErickWong Well, that's an open problem and guess with Apéry's constant it's "the million-dollar question".